# Attach a different packaging of a maven artifact to a deploy?

Tags: android, deployment, maven-2, apk

My maven build is creating an `apklib` package. I've added the jar plugin so that it also creates a JAR after generating sources and compiling. I'd like both the `jar` and `apklib` files to end up in our repository, so I'd like to attach both artifacts to the deploy and install.

I see that a similar question has been [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277697/adding-artifacts-to-standard-maven-deploy), but that deals with an arbitrary file on the file system, not the dynamically-changing name of the artifact generated by the build process.

Answer (score 1):

This is *an* answer, but I wish it were easier:

http://muralikashaboina.sys-con.com/node/419727/mobile (search for attaching additional artifacts)

Answer (score 0):

By default the jar plugin will attach the artifact to the execution, replacing the default output. However you can configure it to attach an additional artifact instead by specifying the `classifier` in the jar-plugin's configuration.

This configuration below created an additional jar artifact which is automatically attached to the project and installed/deployed along with the main artifact. It is distinguished with the classifier **api** and includes only those classes that match the `includes` pattern.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>jar</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classifier>api</classifier>
        <includes>
          <include>**/api/*</include>
        </includes>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling this might be fixed by now but if not please file a request for enhancement and potentially provide a patch that fixes it.